# Convert string to same hex value in c#

Tags: c#

I have a string varaible `str`. This variable has a value `"26"`. Can I convert it into hex that results 0x26 not 0x1A.

Means `str="26"`

```
int iConvert=**SomeConvertionFunction(str)**
```

should result into `iConvert=0x26`

Comment: @SonerGönül why not? `Convert.ToUInt32("26", 16)` returns (int)0x26

Comment: @SonerGönül I know, that is why I wanted help on this forum. Anyways, solution to my problem lies in Sriram's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int hex = int.Parse("26", NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

hex value will be `38` which is the decimal representation of hex number 0x26.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question basically you want to store the Hex value of the string in a int?

having the value 26 or 0x1A is the same.

To convert the int to a string use int.ToString('X');

And please not that 26 in base 10 in equal to 0x1A in base 16.

Comment: I believe the OP is saying that 26 is the hex value, so the result should be 38.

Comment: Yeah that is what I just figured out. haha.